# Is it possible that I can get a Duke University user account to access math videos?

Tags: online-learning

I am an independent student of math and want to use many interesting video courses. Unfortunately the [math video courses of Duke university](https://www4.math.duke.edu/video/video.html) are unavailable for others. So I want to know

> Is there any way to access these courses or is it possible that to get a temporary (and free) user account from Duke University?

Comment: Ask Duke, of course.

Comment: They may not give you free access - perhaps this is material they don’t want in the public domain.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. For future questions, I'd encourage you to ask your question in a somewhat more general fashion. Questions about particular universities' processes are off topic here; but questions about academic customs, or about whom at universities to contact, are often on topic.

Comment: Ok, thank you @academic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commentor wrote, "ask Duke". In practice, that means the following.

Note from the URL that the page is maintained by the math department. If you can, try to figure out who specifically is maintaining the webpage (i.e., a person's name), and contact them. Otherwise, I'd recommend writing to anyone in a position of responsilibity in their math department -- say, the graduate director. Tell them that you are interested in watching their videos, and ask if there's any way you could be permitted to do so.

The most likely outcome is either that they say no, or that you get no response at all -- but in my estimation it's okay to ask, and they might say yes.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to ask Duke is correct, but the most likely outcome is that they will not give you access (or not respond at all). There are two things that are probably more likely to work:

1. **Ask the creator(s) of the videos.** Reaching out directly to the creators of the videos is more likely to get a response than asking some administrator at the university. The creator is probably passionate about what they have made, and if they have the ability to share the videos with you directly, they may do so. (Be sure to state your qualifications and be polite, for maximum chances of getting a response.)
2. **Ask a student at Duke, either someone you know or in an online forum.** Be aware that it may not be allowed for them to share with you.

If it fails, fortunately, there are many other places on the internet with online learning resources that you can look into. I would not get to disheartened if this particular resource is beyond your reach.